# How to pass values to the onchecked event handler of iCheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, icheck

Please how may we pass values to the `onChecked` event handler of iCheck (ver 1.x)?

In my scenario, each radio-button has specific values which I need to pass to the `checked` event handler

How can I get iCheck to execute my function `"score()"` with receives values `onChange`, as in the sample below:

```
<input type="radio" class="checkbox-inline i-checks" name="grp_A" id="opt_1" onchange="score('0508AG08002', 1, 4.0)">
<input type="radio" class="checkbox-inline i-checks" name="grp_A" id="opt_2" onchange="score('05034etw034', 2, 5.0)">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').on('ifChecked', function (v) {
            console.log(v);
        });

        $('.i-checks').iCheck({
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
        });
    });

    function score(matric, qid, grade) {
        console.log(matric, qid, grade);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to move the data you want to pass to iCheck to a `data` attribute in your markup, e.g. to `data-check`. Then you could easily access that from `ifChecked` event like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/mpb2dykL/).

```
<input type="radio" class="..." name="grp_A" id="opt_1" data-check="'0508AG08002', 1, 4.0">
<input type="radio" class="..." name="grp_A" id="opt_2" data-check="'05034etw034', 2, 5.0">

$('input').on('ifChecked', function (v) {
    console.log( $(this).attr("data-check") );
});
```